# How to serve GIFs, JPEGs and PNGs from AWS Lambda

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda

I am using AWS lambda to create a function which serves JS code for a widget.
I also want to serve few images.
Until now I am able to serve SVGs by converting the to binary data but somehow it is not working for GIFs or JPEGs or PNGs

I am using Flask framework for python.
Below is the code snippet

```
def img(filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')
    if(len(ext) >= 2):
        ext = ext[1]
    else:
        ext = ''
    if(ext == 'svg'):
        mime = 'image/svg+xml'
    elif(ext == 'gif'):
        mime = 'image/gif'
    else:
        mime = 'image/'+ext

    filename = 'src/img/'+filename

    if(os.path.isfile(filename)):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as bites:
            return send_file(io.BytesIO(bites.read()), mimetype=mime)
    else:
        return res({'error': True, 'msg': 'File not found'})
```

Comment: Why not just store your binary assets in S3 and serve from there?

Comment: This worked. I was hoping to just go without doing anything other than deploying the the sls code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Daniel, using a public s3 bucket to serve the files works in this case and is much easier than coding the way I was doing.